# Converting a hashmap into a JSON string

Tags: java, json, gson, double-quotes, backslash

I want to convert a hashmap into a json string to send over wire. Here is the code

```
public static void main(String []args) 
    throws JSONException, JsonParseException, JsonMappingException, IOException {

    Map<String,String> varMap = new MyMap<String,String>();
    varMap.put("VAR","123");
    varMap.put("OTHER_VAR","234");
    Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().create();
    String jsonString = gson.toJson(varMap);

    JSONObject json = new JSONObject();
    json.put("Variable",jsonString);
    System.out.println("JSON " + json); 
}
```

The output is

```
JSON {"Variable":"{\"VAR\":\"123\",\"OTHER_VAR\":\"234\"}"}
```

Which I assume does the right thing, but the examples I've found dont include the backslash in the strng. I understand that the backslash escapes the double quotes and hence none of the string replace method work to replace the backslash.

Is there a trick to get the following output?

```
JSON {"Variable":{"VAR":"123","OTHER_VAR":"234"}}
```

Can the custom serialization property be used to somehow not add backslashes?

Comment: See this https://kodejava.org/how-do-i-convert-map-into-json/

Comment: Why are you converting your map into a string instead of just adding the map?

Comment: because in the json, the value is expected to be a string

Comment: Not sure what JSON library you have there, but `new JSONObject(map).toString()` could do what you want

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This should give you the result you want.  You're JSON-encoding a JSON-string and its adding those backslashes to escape those characters.

```
public static void main(String []args) throws JSONException, JsonParseException, JsonMappingException, IOException{

    Map<String, Object> top = new HashMap<String, Object>();

    Map<String, Object> vars = new HashMap<String, Object>();
    vars.put("VAR","123");
    vars.put("OTHER_VAR","234");

    top.put("Variable", vars);

    Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().create();
    String jsonString = gson.toJson(top);
    System.out.println("JSON " + json);
}
```

Comment: should top be map<String, Object> type? The program does not compile

Comment: @user_mda You're right, they should all be Map<String, Object>

Comment: Thank you this gives the expected result but when I use the String in the input json and send over wire it escapes the double quotes with "/".

Comment: This is only on the server side!

Comment: It will always escape characters in a String.  Otherwise it has no idea that the String is JSON-encoded.  ALL Strings will be escaped when converted to JSON.  The only way around that is to build your own JSON builder.

Comment: I see, do u have an example

Comment: You should re-select an answer to this question and make a new one about the String escaping.

Comment: This will not work as expected if you have null as value.

Comment: @RajeeVVenkaT null is not an acceptable value in JSON anyway.  That said, I'm surprised GSON doesn't convert null to the string "null".